# How to do: lateral menu like in "Music" app on Windows 8 / 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, menu, store

I tried everywhere to search how to do a menu like this:

> wstaw.org/m/2014/07/08/menu1.png
>
> wstaw.org/m/2014/07/08/menu2.png

but I found nothing. I found a question in this site too (stackoverflow.com/questions/22613421/windows-8-1-apps-left-menu), but it has no answers.

So, do anyone know how this menu is done?

I want to know how I can do a similar thing: a menu with buttons that bring me to other pages and a button that make smaller this menu.

Comment: What part of it do you want ? Do you want a menu to navigate inside the same frame ? Do you want just the layout ? You need to be more precise in your question

Comment: I want to know how I can do a similar thing: a menu with buttons that bring me to other pages and a button that make smaller this menu.

Comment: Ok, first you need to separate your two needs (the layout, and the navigation thing). First, the layout. Do you know what a VisualState is ?

Comment: Yes, I probably know what is it. Have you got any code samlples of it? Becouse I tried many times to do it using simple  controls and blend, but nothing.