# How to implement facebook like menu (left menu) in windows store app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Basically, I want to be able to create a menu which on clicking on some button will appear from left (or right) and on clicking anywhere on main screen the user would be able to dissmis the menu. For example the facebook app has something similar on all platforms (so on Windows 8 also).

I have found a solution for Windows phone (http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.cz/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html), which is not the way to go for Windows 8. Maybe I could use some hand made animation for aflyover, which would be in default outside of viewport. However, I guess there must be better or ideally already proofed solution.

Also I found two questions here on SO, which asked for same thing I guess, but no answers there ...
[How to do: lateral menu like in "Music" app on Windows 8 / 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628543/how-to-do-lateral-menu-like-in-music-app-on-windows-8-8-1) and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613421/windows-8-1-apps-left-menu

I know, that it is not the best way on windows platform to implement menu (we have top app bar, right), but our customer just wants this.

I would like to ask for some hints or ideally a code for a native implementation for Windows 8.1 using XAML (C# or VB.NET). Thanks to everybody who will give it a thought.

Answer (score 1):

You'd put a `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"` in a `ScrollViewer`. Put three panels in the `StackPanel` - let's make them `Grids` and call them: left, middle and right. On `SizeChanged` events of the `ScrollViewer` - set the `Width` and `Height` of the middle grid to the same values as `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the `ScrollViewer` and perhaps set the left and right grids to be a little bit narrower to leave space to see a little bit of the middle panel when you scroll to the ends. Make the `ScrollViewer` scroll horizontally by setting `Horizontal/VerticalScrollMode` and scroll bar visibilities and make the `ScrollViewer` snap to your grid panels by setting the [`HorizontalSnapPointsType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalsnappointstype.aspx) and [`HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalsnappointsalignment.aspx) properties. Also set `IsHorizontalRailEnabled` on the horizontal `ScrollViewer` to true if you have any vertical `ScrollViewers` in your panels and make their `IsVerticalRailEnabled="true"` so only one of them scrolls depending on the manipulation direction. Finally - put a transparent overlay panel as a top child of the middle panel handle the tap events on the overlay to scroll the middle panel back into view when it isn't centered and in the handlers of the menu buttons scroll the horizontal `ScrollViewer` to the start/end.

Comment: Thanks Filip. Your solution seems interesting, I will try to use it most likely. Did you use it already somewhere? Or is it merely a concept?

Comment: I played with it and I'm planning to create a universal menu control that will use these concepts.